# Python 2.7.6 Pydoop installation fail on Ubuntu

Tags: python, hadoop, ubuntu-14.04, python-2.6

I am facing this error while installing pydoop package:

```
root@ubuntu:~# pip install pydoop
Downloading/unpacking pydoop
  Downloading pydoop-1.0.0.tar.gz (931kB): 931kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pydoop/setup.py) egg_info for package pydoop
    using setuptools version 15.0
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/pydoop/setup.py", line 59, in <module>
        import pydoop.hdfs.core.impl as hdfsimpl
      File "pydoop/hdfs/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
        init()
      File "pydoop/hdfs/__init__.py", line 93, in init
        pydoop.hadoop_classpath(), _ORIG_CLASSPATH, pydoop.hadoop_conf()
      File "pydoop/__init__.py", line 106, in hadoop_classpath
        return _PATH_FINDER.hadoop_classpath(hadoop_home)
      File "pydoop/hadoop_utils.py", line 540, in hadoop_classpath
        hadoop_home = self.hadoop_home()
      File "pydoop/hadoop_utils.py", line 399, in hadoop_home
        PathFinder.__error("hadoop home", "HADOOP_HOME")
      File "pydoop/hadoop_utils.py", line 385, in __error
        raise ValueError("%s not found, try setting %s" % (what, env_var))
    ValueError: hadoop home not found, try setting HADOOP_HOME
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    using setuptools version 15.0
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/pydoop/setup.py", line 59, in <module>

    import pydoop.hdfs.core.impl as hdfsimpl

  File "pydoop/hdfs/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>

    init()

  File "pydoop/hdfs/__init__.py", line 93, in init

    pydoop.hadoop_classpath(), _ORIG_CLASSPATH, pydoop.hadoop_conf()

  File "pydoop/__init__.py", line 106, in hadoop_classpath

    return _PATH_FINDER.hadoop_classpath(hadoop_home)

  File "pydoop/hadoop_utils.py", line 540, in hadoop_classpath

    hadoop_home = self.hadoop_home()

  File "pydoop/hadoop_utils.py", line 399, in hadoop_home

    PathFinder.__error("hadoop home", "HADOOP_HOME")

  File "pydoop/hadoop_utils.py", line 385, in __error

    raise ValueError("%s not found, try setting %s" % (what, env_var))

ValueError: hadoop home not found, try setting HADOOP_HOME
```

---

Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pydoop
Storing debug log for failure in /home/abhimanyu/.pip/pip.log

Comment: Do you have HADOOP_HOME setup? For me it is set but still the same error. Any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo sh -c "ls ; export HADOOP_HOME=/yourpathtohadoopinstallation/; export JAVA_HOME=/yourpathtojavainstallation/; pip install pydoop"
```

That did the trick for me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update /etc/profile and set HADOOP_HOME and JAVA_HOME. Once /etc/profile has been updated, log out and log back in.

Now run sudo -E pip install pydoop

The -E preserves the environment

See https://github.com/crs4/pydoop/issues/170 for more information

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment on the answer posted by saseaturtle. I put it here.

I met the exactly same problem at first, pydoop complain about can't find HADOOP_HOME and HADOOP_PREFIX while these two field are just there and the following command can show their value correctly.

```
echo $HADOOP_HOME; echpHADOOP_PREFIX
```

I tried the solution posted by saseaturtle, but pydoop complain about missing javac this time though type **javac** in shell can show correct feedback and all those $JAVA_HOME or $JAVA_LIB environment are set correctly.

Finally I successfully installed pydoop by using the following command:

```
sudo sh -c "export PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_92/bin:$PATH; export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.3; export JAVA_HOME=/home/why/download/jdk1.8.0_92; pip install pydoop"
```

My guess is that all the above problem came from environment setting since the command was run as sudo. The root user may not have those needed enviroment variables set as the current the user and that's why adding some export command solve the problem.